# Python Logistic Regression Positional Argument

Tags: python, regression

The following is my code:

```
x = hrdf[['JobSatisfaction', 'HourlyRate', 'WorkLifeBalance']]
y = hrdf['Attrition']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
log_regression = LogisticRegression

log_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = log_regression.predict(X_test)
```

and the error I receive is:

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Not sure where I went wrong with fitting the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `log_regression = LogisticRegression`, and it is thinking its an object type, not an instance.

You just need to make it `log_regression = LogisticRegression()`

Comment: MrFrknFantastic is right, the 2 arguments occupy the missing self argument and the x argument which is why the error says y is missing.

Comment: of course! thanks a ton!